How to read the curve in fundamental group of a Poincaré homology sphere?
I want to understand the fundamental group of a Poincaré homology sphere obtained by Dehn. I do not understand how to interpret the curve $p$ in the following picture found in the book I am reading, i.e. J. Stillwell, Classical topology and Combinatorial group theory (MR1211642, Zbl 0774.57002). How to compute the fundamental group of the trefoil knot complement in the picture below?
In the book the Author takes the fundamental group of a trefoil knot complement and adds an extra relation associated to the said curve curve as $a_1a_2^2a_1a^{-3}$.


The labels of the picture do not mention $p$! Please correct the typos in your question and make it clear what part of the picture you are asking about.

Thank you very much ! I have a little  difficulty to understand the material. I  am reading  the part the fundamental group of a Poincare homology sphere. and i do not inderstand how it was computed

@HJRW, I fixed the typos (except I don't know what "definte" is supposed to be).

You can find an answer (computation of the fundamental group of torus knot complements)  in any textbook in knot theory and also in many algebraic topology textbooks (say, Hatcher's). It is not a research-level question.

The homology sphere is obtained by drilling out the pictured solid torus and gluing it back in via a different identification.  The pictured curve is in the knot exterior, so by inclusion it's also in the homology sphere.  It looks like the figure is using a standard presentation of the fundamental group of the knot exterior in its notation -- this isn't enough to capture the curve's isotopy class but it sufficies for some homotopy computations.

Thank you very much!
